based on array of object on key array list covert each key to new object of array list
"Items" having array of object in each object there is key called "ImpactedCIs" array list. Based on each array list need to generate new object based on "ImpactedCIs" array of objects. Need a possible new array of objects with an existing key element.
                  "items": [
            {
                "ImpactedCIs": ["MJUDKHJ112O","FTTM_ZTF647"],
                "CMSStatus": "5",
                "ActualStartTime": "1700003455",
                "ActualEndTime": "1700003455",
                "PM": "Sample",
                "PMContact": "45345435"
            }
        ]
                    
                Result: 
                "items": [
        {
            "ImpactedCIs": "MJUDKHJ112O",
            "CMSStatus": "5",
            "ActualStartTime": "1700003455",
            "ActualEndTime": "1700003455",
            "PM": "Sample",
            "PMContact": "45345435"
        },
        {
            "ImpactedCIs": "FTTM_ZTF647",
            "CMSStatus": "5",
            "ActualStartTime": "1700003455",
            "ActualEndTime": "1700003455",
            "PM": "Sample",
            "PMContact": "45345435"
        }
    ]


With some loops you can achieve it. In order to copy (shallow) an object I can use { ... obj }


var items = [{
  "ImpactedCIs": ["MJUDKHJ112O", "FTTM_ZTF647"],
  "CMSStatus": "5",
  "ActualStartTime": "1700003455",
  "ActualEndTime": "1700003455",
  "PM": "Sample",
  "PMContact": "45345435"
}]

var result = []
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.ImpactedCIs.forEach(function(ImpactedCI) {
    var new_item = {... item}
    new_item.ImpactedCIs = ImpactedCI
    result.push (new_item)
  })
})

console.log(result)



